# Cannot run evilvte (VTE terminal emulator) as user - except via SSH

Tags: x11, gnome, terminal-emulator

I have compiled evilvte from source, on an old Nokia N810 tablet. When I try to run it as user, it opens and then immediately closes. If I try as su root it works fine. I can also run run it as user if I log into the device via ssh (either remotely or on the device)

The only error I get is that gnome-helper cannot be found (it isn't installed or available for this device) What should I look for to fix this?

The o/s is very old Debian based (Lenny I think)